# When is JOIN executed in this case?

Tags: mysql, join

Let's say I select data from table "posts":

```
id   |  bigint(20)   |  PK
text |  varchar(400)
```

and a table "likes":

```
user_id  |  bigint(20)
post_id  |  bigint(20)
```

those 2 fields are joined as primary key

Let's say my select on the table "posts" with 500'000 records is simply

```
SELECT id, text FROM posts LIMIT 0,20
```

and I need to know which posts have a like (there can only be one per user/post, see primary-key definition). So I could just do

```
SELECT id, text FROM posts LEFT JOIN likes ON posts.id = likes.post_id LIMIT 0,20
```

Will the query join on 20 records or on all 500'000 of table "posts"? No column of "likes" is used in any WHERE/GROUP clause in my effective query.

Output of

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT id
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN likes ON posts.id = likes.post_id
LIMIT 0 , 20

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  posts   index   NULL    PRIMARY 16  NULL    58  Using index
1   SIMPLE  likes   ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   legendaily.posts.id 1   Using index
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT id, text FROM posts LEFT JOIN likes ON posts.id = likes.post_id LIMIT 0,20` ?

Comment: Are there currently 58 rows in your table? If so, it looks like MySQL is JOINing everything and then LIMITing that.

Comment: yes, there are :( this is horrible! What can I do? Would a subselect change anything? Otherwise, I'll have to do a 2nd query with a WHERE IN(list of post_ids)...

Comment: It doesn't have to be all bad. Can you add some more posts and likes to the database? (just write a script that writes random posts and likes random posts). It could be that at certain point MySQL will switch to checking the indices only, instead of JOINing the complete tables, but at this point JOINing the tables is cheap because they are so small so MySQL opts for that.

Comment: Is this the plan of the real database? If it is, i think you might be doing "premature optimization". Trying to optimize SQL at this point is not very meaningful.

Comment: What do you mean exactly @lunr? This is my localhost-DB, on production there are hundreds of thousands of posts. @ScallioXTX I'll do that. Although I had to change to a subselect for other reasons right now - do you know how the database will handle that? I hope the subselect will only be executed AFTER the LIMIT?

Comment: Optimizing questions cannot be answered without the real execution plan. The same SQL may run differently with a different set of data.